# Sample regression, x = months, huge bandwidths

Tags: r, time, regression

I have two vectors, `x` and `y`.

`x` is a vector where each entry represents a month for a period of several years, so I have (let's say) 10 years of data, then `length(x) = 120` and so on. 
(I have used the "posix.ct" command so they really are "months" in that sense, but couldn't I just have `x` as a numerical vector like `c(1:n)` or something, since I already know which month and which year a certain element of `c(1:n)` corresponds to? i.e if `x = c(1:n)`, I know that `x[13]` is february of the second year and so on..)

y is a vector where each elements is an observation of a particular variable at a certain month. 
So the observed data is grouped like this (january,0.123), (february,2.125) and so on.
I have two vectors for the months;

```
x1 = seq(as.POSIXct("YYYY-MM-DD", tz="GMT"),
       as.POSIXct("YYYY-MM-DD", tz="GMT"),
       by="month")
x2 = c(1:length(x1))
```

What I want to do is to run ksmooth:

```
plot(x1,y)
smooth = ksmooth(x2,y,"normal")     
lines(smooth)
```

The reason that I use x1 in the plot() command is that I don't know how to otherwise get the x-axis in time.

R should automatically find a decent smoothing parameter when I haven't specified anything. The result is that ksmooth$y is equal to the input vector y! Also, a vertical bar is produced in the plot. If I replace `x2` by `x1` in the code above, `ksmooth$y` is NA for all values except for the first and last, which equal those of the input `y`.

So i try some bandwidths:
`h = 0.1`: now `smooth$y = y`, as before. A vertical bar is produced (it is the same color as I specified in the `lines()` command, so it must have to do with the `ksmooth` command.)
`h = 10`: get some non-strange results for smooth$y, however, a vertical bar is produced as before.

Then, I tried the crazy idea of very large bandwidths;
`h = 1e+06`: This produced nothing when I used `x1` and `x2` as in the code above. When I changed `x2` to `x1` however, I get some good results. For `h = 1e+09` (that's huge!!) I get a very nice result. (I get a curve that fits the data and looks nice)
But `h = 1e+09`, is that reasonable? in all the examples I have looked h is something betweeen 0.1 and 10, give or take. heard something about a rule of thumb: h should equal n^(-1/5) where n is the number of data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the one thing that you are missing is that R *doesn't* find a decent smoothing parameter when you haven't specified anything, it just uses a bandwidth of 0.5, which is totally useless in your case.

The other thing you might be missing is that in `ksmooth` the `bandwidth` parameter is in terms of `x`. When `ksmooth` takes an `x` value of `Date`, it converts it to a numeric, which is the number of *seconds*. Therefore, your bandwidth will be measured in seconds, an undesirable result. When `ksmooth` takes an `x` value of months, it will default to a bandwidth of 0.5 months, also undesirable.

What you want to do is specify a reasonable bandwidth for the `x` that you are using. Here is an example:

```
x1 = seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01", tz="GMT"),
       as.POSIXct("2010-12-31", tz="GMT"),
       by="month")
x2 = c(1:length(x1)) 
set.seed(1)
y = runif(length(x1))

plot(x1,y,type='l')
smooth = ksmooth(x2,y,"normal")     
lines(x1,smooth$y,col='blue',lwd=2)
lines(x1,ksmooth(x2,y,'normal',bandwidth=2)$y,col='red',lwd=2)
lines(x1,ksmooth(x2,y,'normal',bandwidth=10)$y,col='green',lwd=2)
lines(x1,ksmooth(x2,y,'normal',bandwidth=20)$y,col='orange',lwd=2)
```

[image: Smoothed random time series]